# React Router DOM routing

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have been trying to use the upgraded react router syntax in my old project but I keep getting a blank white screen

After routing, I am expected to see my header, sidebar and every other component included in my App.js but all I get on my browser is a blank white screen

The codes:

```
<div className="App">
      <Router>
      <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/search/:searchTerm' element={ 
            <div className='app_page'>
              <Sidebar />
              <SearchPage />
            </div>
          } />
         <Route path='/' element={
      <div className='app_page'>
      <Sidebar />
      <RecommendedVideos />
      </div>
      } />
      </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
    );
```

Comment: Please provide some information about what `react-router` version you're using

Comment: React Router v6.14.2

Comment: I just got it fixed. I only had to remove <Router></Router> from my codes